# input lose focus on setState React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Whenever I am using setState my focus of input lost.

Where I am going wrong please tell me.

I am new to React.

This is my child component here I am using [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/):-

```
    const { onChangeEmail, onChangePassword, onPressSignIn, emailValue, passwordValue } = props;
          <TextField
            onChange={onChangeEmail}
            value={emailValue}
            variant="outlined"
            id="email"
            label="Enter your email"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
        />

        <TextField
            onChange={onChangePassword}
            value={passwordValue}
            variant="outlined"
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
        />
```

my Parent component:-

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
})
                           <SigninForm
                            onChangeEmail={(evt) => {
                                setState({
                                    ...state,
                                    email : evt.target.value
                                })
                            }}
                            emailValue={state.email}
                            passwordValue={state.password}
                            onChangePassword={(evt) => {
                                setState({
                                    ...state,
                                    password : evt.target.value
                                })
                            }}
                        />
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does this works? I mean does the state changes when input is changed?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with the latest `@material-ui/core`. Make sure your dependencies are up to date. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-blur-issue-s8qzc).

Comment: yes state changes @Abhishek

Comment: @superhawk610 sure I will look into dependencies. thanks for CodeSandbox

Answer (score 2):

Your `useState` hook triggers render `SigninForm` each time you type as a result you loose focus. You can try `onBlur` to update state on focus out event and don't pass values to input

Comment: I have one issue when I am using `onBlur` my state does update but input get blank when loose focus. And I have removed value as well.